# SSLv2Hello - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to call an SSL protected web service running on JDK7 / WildFly 8.2 with a Java 6 (update 31) based client.

The first problem I encountered on the client was:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message

By setting `javax.net.debug` to `all` on both sides, I got the following hint on the server side:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLv2Hello is disabled

Quick research [shows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html) that,

> SSLv2Hello disabled by default on the client: In Java SE 7, SSLv2Hello is removed from the default enabled protocol list on the client.

So I have tried to enable `SSLv2Hello` on WildFly in `standalone.xml`:

```
<https-listener name="https" 
                socket-binding="https" 
                security-realm="UndertowRealm"
                enabled-protocols="SSLv2, SSLv2Hello, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2"
                />
```

And the result on the server is:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

So I realize, I should be trying to force TLS on the *client* instead of enabling *SSLv2Hello* on the *server*. I have tried to set `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");` before my web service call with no effect.

What should I configure and how, to get the handshake working?

I have printed the supported cipher suites from the default `SSLSocketFactory` on the server:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
```

Comment: You should test the server which protocols and chipher suites are supported: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: @Robert Since I have a local server I cannot use the tool you provided. I have added a list of the *default* ciphers for the `SSLSocketFactory`.

Comment: If it is a local server use the tool "sslyze" and/or ask the amin of the server how the server is configured. And if the server does not support TLS1.1/1.2 kick the admin's ass... BTW. Java 6 and 7 are outdated. Only use Java 8.

Comment: @Robert WildFly 8.2 supports TLS1.1/1.2 AFAIK. I am not allowed to upgrade Java 6 for the client apps ;(

Comment: It is probably tempting to vote to close this as 'cannot reproduce', as current versions of Java cannot produce this behaviour,because SSLv2Hello has been removed. But it needs to stay here for historical reasons. We've seen new questions about Java 1.4.1 more than ten years after it came out.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to enable SSLv2 at the server. You need to *disable* the SSLv2Hello *pseudo*-protocol at the *client*, by removing `SSLv2Hello` from the enabled TLS protocols *and leaving the others*:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSV1.1,TLSV1.2");
```

and maybe `SSLv3` if that makes it happy: it won't for much longer, so try not to have to do that.

Note that it is a pseudo-protocol. It is not SSLv2, it is a compatibility measure to allow certain arguably broken servers to accept the hello. The session however operates at SSLv3 or above. It is also obsolete.

Comment: Caveat: sysprop `https.protocols` only works on code using `HttpsUrlConnection` (including indirectly), or Apache httpclient if the code selects useSystemProperties. Other libraries or standalone code may require a different setting, or even a code change.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably enable the SSLv2 protocol at the JVM but that is extremely inadvisable because that is a serious security risk.

The clients are using an outdated and insecure protocol and should be updated to TLSv1.1 or TLSv.1.2. That will require at least Java 7 but Java 8 would be better as Robert mentioned.

More info could be found at https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https including a table of support TLS protocols by version.

Comment: You can't enable SSLv2 at the client. Sun/Oracle Java has never supported it.

Comment: I should have mentioned that SSLv2Hello was enabled in older Java versions and disabled in Java 7. Still can be reenabled if needed.

Comment: I already mentioned that a month previously. SSLv2Hello is not the same thing as SSLv2. Java has never supported SSLv2. Ergo the clients are not 'using an outdated and insecure protocol'. They are using SSLv2Hello as a compatibility measure. – EJP 1 hour ago

Comment: While your answer apparently isn't 100% correct - I still upvoted it for providing the great link on diagnosing https issues